# How do I configure ESLint to check for TypeScript class property JSDoc comments?

Tags: typescript, jsdoc, typescript-eslint, eslint-plugin-jsdoc

I have a TypeScript application (4.0.x) that includes the following packages:

```
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.0.1",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.0.1",
"@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.4",
"eslint": "^7.8.1",
"eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^30.3.1",
```

My .eslintrc.js includes the following:

```
'extends': [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    'eslint:recommended',
    '@vue/typescript/recommended',
    "plugin:jsdoc/recommended"
],
parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020
},
plugins: [
    "jsdoc"
],
rules: {
    'jsdoc/require-property-description': 1,
    'jsdoc/require-description': 1,
    'jsdoc/require-param-type': 'off',
    'jsdoc/require-returns-type': 'off',
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off'
}
```

When I run ESLint against my code I want it to return an error or warning if a property defined on a class doesn't include a JSDoc description.

For example, with the following code I would expect a message regarding `id`, `mainCharacters`, and `state` missing JSDoc descriptions.

```
export default class Party {
    public id = -1;
    public mainCharacters: Character[] = [];
    public state: PartyState;
    /**
     * Location index.
     */
    public location = 0;
```

Based upon the documentation it doesn't appear the `jsdoc/require-property*` rules would work, but I did try switching them on anyway and they're not reporting missing JSDocs.

```
'jsdoc/require-property': 1,
'jsdoc/require-property-description': 1,
'jsdoc/require-property-name': 1,
'jsdoc/require-property-type': 1,
```

What ESLint rule(s) am I missing that would report missing JSDocs on TypeScript properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I should note that `eslint-plugin-jsdoc`'s rules are incremental. If you don't have any jsdoc block at all, you first need to add the `jsdoc/require-jsdoc` rule so it will complain unless you have at least something like:

```
/**
 *
 */
```

...above your structure of interest. In your case, you do have "recommended" which includes this rule, so you're covered there.

Similarly, the rules like `require-property-description` or `require-property-name` will only work if you already have a `@property` on a given block.

Secondly, the `require-property` rule has a different purpose than what you are trying to do. It is instead used to report that a `@property` is present when a jsdoc block has a `@namespace` tag (used for plain objects) or a `@typedef` tag (used for defining types).

JSDoc does [indicate](https://jsdoc.app/tags-property.html) the tag can be used for the *static* properties of classes, so the `eslint-plugin-jsdoc` project could in theory adapt the rule to check for consistency between any `@property` tags in a jsdoc block above the class and those properties used within the class, but I'm not sure how popular this would be given that most projects seem to prefer adding the docs in the manner in your example (i.e., above the properties themselves).

You could use `require-property`, along with the other `require-property-*` rules too if you used the `@property` tag right above your properties, but I wouldn't think you would really want that, especially since I'm not sure how documentation tools treat `@property` in this context--it seems from the [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#classes) that `@type` is used instead--to check that `@type` has a curly-bracketed type, use [`jsdoc/valid-types`](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-jsdoc/#valid-types) and you could use [`jsdoc/match-description`](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-jsdoc/#match-description) to indicate that the tag should have a description or use [`jsdoc/require-description`](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-jsdoc/#require-description) so as to enforce a description above the tag, using either of these two description-related rules' `contexts` option with `ClassProperty` inside since they don't check properties by default).

But to finally get back to the most important part of what you need, you will want to use [jsdoc/require-jsdoc](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-jsdoc/#require-jsdoc). However, by default `require-jsdoc` only checks for `FunctionDeclaration`, i.e., for regular function declarations, but you can use the `require` or `contexts` option for more precise control, i.e., in your case you could add `{contexts: ['ClassProperty']}`.

Comment: I am extending `plugin:jsdoc/recommended`, so I've already got `jsdoc/require-jsdoc` warning, but manually adding it as `'jsdoc/require-jsdoc': [1, { contexts: ['ClassDeclaration', 'ClassProperty', 'FunctionDeclaration'] }]`, and setting the same for `jsdoc/require-description` looks to be giving me exactly what I'm looking for. :)

Comment: Cool. I've updated to take account for the fact you are using the rule through recommended.